# Android Intent opens inside other app

Tags: android, android-intent, cordova-plugins, tel

I am trying to open my own app whenever there is a "tel:" tag inside a link.
So I am using an intent-filter like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>
```

But when tapping a link my App opens inside the browser (when looking a all opened apps I can see myApp window within the browser, plus my App which I already opened in the background).

How can I tell the intent to (re-)open my App and not inside the browser (or other app which triggers the intent)?

I open the app using the cordova webintent plugin:

```
https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent.git
```

Implemented inside the javascript with the following calls:

```
window.plugins.webintent.onNewIntent(returnTelIntent);
window.plugins.webintent.getUri(returnTelIntent);
function returnTelIntent() {};
```

Comment: can you show us the code that should open your app?

Comment: added the plugin and the calls for cordova

Comment: Has anybody found a solution? I am having exactly the same problem...

Comment: UP. I am having exactly the same problem

Comment: Double UP.  I am launching app2 from within app1, and app2 is opening inside of app1 - not as a new window.  I need to launch app2 into its own window.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the Android launch mode. Look here:

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en